# PC is crashing every time I unlock it

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and every time I lock and unlock the PC it will crash after 15 sec

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I have captured the  `cat /var/log/syslog`  but I don't know what to look for

Comment: Hold down the shift key as you reboot, and you'll be able to select "recovery mode". Is your system plugged in? Is your battery healthy? `acpi -V`

Comment: yes my system is plugged in and my battery is healthy

Comment: as for to booting in recovery mode what is the added value?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with pycharm  when I stop using it didn't have the issue anymore